# tcl interact with wget

Tags: tcl, wget

In my tcl script I'm using wget to download a file from http address.

The code:

```
catch {open "|wget -q --output-document Tags.xlsx --http-user=$env(USER) --ask-password \"http://web.com/sites/Documents/Names.xlsx\""} fh
fileevent $fh writable {
puts $fh "password"
}
```

The Error:

```
channel is not writable
    while executing
"fileevent $fh writable {
    puts $fh "password"
}"
```

Why channel is not writable? 
When running pure wget it request password in prompt.

Comment: I can't tell for sure if you are going to read as well as write. If doing both, _be careful_ as you can run into problems with pipe starvation due to buffering. (Many programs change their behavior when not writing to a terminal, but I forget whether `wget` is one of these.)

Comment: @Donal Fellows,at the end I decided that it is much better to use expect package instead resolving pipe problems. I've replaced the catch and fileevent to spawn, expect and interact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that the channel isn't writeable. Try opening it with

```
open "......" r+
```

to allow both read and write access.

Comment: +1: The default open mode is `r` (the most common option for files) but for pipes that you want to write to, you need `w`, `a`, `r+`, `w+` or `a+`. Or to use the POSIX flag list with `RDWR` or `WRONLY`.